# React hook doesn't update state and component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, kibana

I'm pretty new with React and I'm facing some trouble. I'm writing a Kibana plugin and I can't understand why my table does not update:

```
  const getAllConfigurations = () => {
    axios.get('../api/chimera-events-generator/configurations/get-all-configurations').then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.data.ok) {
        setResponseTab(res.data.data);
        setConfigurations(res.data.data);
      }
    });
  }

  const refresh = () => {
    axios.get('../api/chimera-events-generator/get-all-info').then(res => {
      if (res.data.ok) {      
        var tabTmp = responseTab;
        tabTmp.push({
          name: 'ajeje'
        });
        console.log(tabTmp);
        setResponseTab(tabTmp);
      }
    }).catch(error => {

    })

  }
```

If I add a call to "getAllConfigurations" inside the refresh function, just before the rest call, it works fine. But without the "getAllConfigurations" call inside the refresh function, the table does not update at all. The row "ajeje" does not appear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming `responseTab` is your state variable, and you are mutating it by calling `tabTmp.push`. React will not see the state change since you are updating with the same array reference.

Comment: `var tabTmp = responseTab;` does not break the reference to the state variable. You'd need to instead do something like `var tabTmp = [...responseTab];`

Comment: You're both totally right, thanks!